# Custom control spellchecker silverlight not working

Tags: silverlight, telerik, spell-checking, silverlight-5.0

I am facing issue with my custom textbox class control which I am passing to spell checker of rad spell checker of telerik not working.

When I use normal textbox control and passing that control to spell checker class its working but I created new class and inherited that class with textbox class and passing that new custom control of textbox with rad spell checker telerik not working.

It gives error of invalid control type of spellchecker.

What I need to do to achieve and make custom textbox working with telerik spell checker?

Comment: Is there any outcome to make it done?

Comment: Have you asked on Telerik's forum?

Comment: Yes, but no luck :( If you can help me getting it worked with custom textbox then its good.  I just inherited main Textbox class with my another class Class CustomTextbox : Textbox.

Comment: I'm not using Telerik's controls, but I see questions about them quite often on SO. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I am also just wondering and even telerik forum says that only Textbox will work.. It will not work if Textbox class inherited and custom control created and passed. We already have Textbox as base class.